# How to solve this integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Is there any easy way to solve this integration?
$$\int \frac{3x}{(x^2+x+1)^3}dx$$

Comment: It is already written in that form ($A=B=C=D=F=0$, $E=3$). What comes now it the integration. You can begin with completing the square in $x^2+x+1$. Then change variable to make it into the form $\int\frac{Ay+B}{(y^2+C)^3}$.

Comment: @Hector Then I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Have you tried completing the square on the denominator?

Comment: @Amzoti I solve the first term, but still no idea how to continue to solve the second term...

Comment: For the second term you can replace the $1$ in the numerator by $x^2+x+1-x^2-x$ and separate into the fraction with $x^2+x+1$ in the numerator and the fraction with $-x^2-x$ in the numerator. Nah, it is going to get to ugly and magic. Try what Amzoti is saying but after completing the square. That way you can see it better what is the intention.

Comment: The idea is that you get $\frac{a}{(y^2+a)}$ and then replace the $a$ in the numerator by $y^2+a-y^2$. Then separate the fraction. The first one cancels and reduces the exponent $3$. The second one you factor $-y^2$ as $-y\cdot y$ and integrate by parts using one $y$ as one of the factors and the rest of the expression as the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(a)=\displaystyle\int\frac{3x}{x^2+x+a}dx$, and then differentiate twice with regard to *a*.